# Have we completed Diablo 3 in 9 hours?

Tags: diablo-iii

My friend and i decided to play some Diablo 3. We played for almost 9 hours straight and killed Diablo on the hard difficult. We reached level 41.

We think 9 hours is short for a game like Diablo 3.

- Have we missed something?
- Why are we only level 41?
- Is there more story?

Comment: The story is only a fraction of the Diablo games; increase difficulty and start again from the beginning until you are at max level. Once you are at max level, you grind for better max-level loot. And honestly, I'd say 9 hours is a fairly decent length for a a game's story mode.

Comment: But we did it on hard.. Isnt that the hardest?

Comment: [nope](http://i.imgur.com/VZ7h8Dr.png)

Comment: Unless you're playing the console version, maybe?  It has a different difficulty structure than the PC version.

Comment: Most game story lines are only 8 hours, and with all side quests around 24.

Answer (score 5):

Basically you finished the storyline, in normal difficulty. If you were playing for the story then I'm afraid there isn't much more than that. However if you like being challenged you can :

- Try higher difficulties and push your character to level 60 then earn some Paragon Point
- Try another class
- Try to complete all achievements
- Purchase the Reaper of Souls expansion

Purchasing the expansion will bring you the following features :

- A new Act (The Act V).
- A new class (Crusader)
- Your character can now reach level 70

Upon completing the last Act you will unlock :

- The Adventure Mode with bounty hunting, Nephalem rifts (both bringing endless hours of gameplay) and Greater Rifts for some competition.

Comment: We did it on hard.. But did we do it fast?

Comment: 9h is pretty decent. I wouldnt say fast concidering that running the full storyline takes for me now about 20min. Plus there is an achivemetn for finishing each act in less than 1 hour.

Comment: @user76835 Hard to say, as multiplayer skews things a bit, but according to [HLTB](http://www.howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=2514) you and your friend had a decently brisk pace for completing the base story from scratch.

Comment: 1 HOUR?! But then you need to be max level right?

Comment: @user76835, not necessarily.

Comment: @WizLiz how do you do the full storyline in 20 min without skipping quests?

Comment: @z per act*. With the danetta set for DH + tactical advantage, you can vault permanently without worrying about ever stopping again. 20 min for the whole game seems a bit impossible but whyt not

Comment: ah ok, that makes more sense.  Yea, danetta set for DH is awesome for stuff like that, and also split bounties.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't missed anything. If you play fast and do not explore every area in the game thoroughly, you will end it fairly quick.

The game has more difficulties, but if you've done it on the highest one it does not mean you are over.

You can play 5 different classes, 6 with the expansion and for each class you can get different loot that affects your play style.

Diablo is RPG hack'n'slash game, repetitive at first glance, but the rewarding system (loot) is what keeps people playing. You are always striving towards better gear. :)

Either you love it or you hate it.